# Knex select from multiple tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I want to run following SQL with knex:

```
select * from (
  (select * from foo)
  union all
  (select * from bar)) as biz limit 10 offset 20;
```

Is there a way to do it without `knex.raw`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

knex does support `union` and `unionAll`. it's documented

```
knex.select().from(function() {
    this.select().from('foo')
        .unionAll(function() {
            this.select().from('bar')
        }).as('biz')
}).limit(10).offset(20).toString()
```

Output:

```
select * from (select * from `foo` union all select * from `bar`) as `biz` limit 10 offset 20
```